# Using a diode in the output to reduce voltage reversal

Tags: diodes

I have the following schematic. This is a NE555 connected to have a frequency around 10k at a 90% duty cycle.

[image]

This is my simulated output:

[image]

This is my real output at 555_out.

[image]

My understanding is that the diode D3 should stop the voltage reversal here.  I am unsure what model of diode I am currently using, only that it is 15V and I have it facing the proper direction.

[image]

What else can I do to reduce this "voltage reversal"? Please let me know what other information I can provide.  My main concern is that I do not know the model name of the diode and hence have no access to the datasheet.

Comment: Isn't that ringing from the oscilloscope probe ?

Comment: D3 has got nothing to do with the ringing.

Comment: @Rahmany I'm still new to this, what do you mean by probe ringing?

Comment: Please refer to my answer below

Comment: Add a 100n-1u capacitor paralleled with C4. Ground lead of scope nearest of 555 gnd. I guess also you are not using a breadboard.

Comment: Indeed. 100uF is a ridiculous value for a decoupling cap, whereas 100nF is very common. Perhaps needless to say, this cap needs to be placed as close to the Vcc pin as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, this looks like ringing due to inductive loading from the oscilloscope probe.

Generally, oscilloscope probes act like an RC low-pass filter:

[image]

*Source:*  https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/an-introduction-to-oscilloscope-probes/

However, using a long lead for the ground connection (i.e., an alligator clip lead) introduces an inductance between the ground of the scope and the DUT:

[image]

(Excuse my paint skills)

The alligator lead in question :

[image]

This unwanted inductance alongside the capacitance of the scope and the compensating capacitance of the probe will act as an LC filter that has a resonant frequency of:

\$ f_{osc} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}} \$

If your signal's rise time is faster than \$ f_{osc} \$ or rather its equivalent period, you will see oscillations after each transition. You can see that the amplitude of the ringing (in your case) is much greater on a falling edge than on a rising edge. Since the latter is much slower than the former. (I'm basing this remark on the line breaks on the falling edges is 1 break while on the rising edge it's 4 breaks).

#### Solution

To *compensate* this problem, you can use the compensation capacitor of the probe to decrease \$ C_{Comp} \$ and thus increase \$ f_{osc} \$. To do that, refer to your oscilloscope manual. But generally, it's a common procedure across all vendors. For example : [Compensating the Probes](https://www.tek.com/en/documents/primer/setting-and-using-oscilloscope#C5section5:%7E:text=Passive%20attenuation%20voltage,wave%20are%20square.)

Or use a better ground connection: this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420711/is-this-type-of-scope-probe-homemade#:%7E:text=The%20purpose%20of%20these%20short%20probe%20leads%20is%20to%20decrease%20inductance%20of%20leads%20(ground%20in%20particular)%20and%20gain%20few%20dozens%20of%20MHz%20to%20overall%20probe%27s%20bandwidth.%20And%20to%20reduce%20unwanted%20parasitic%20interference%20from%20nearby%20signals.%20Here%20is%20the%20detail%3A) discusses that

*Te next part is not part of the answer to your question, but I thought it's nice to know.*

##### On a different note: Using the inductive loading to your advantage

You can use this inductance introduced by the ground lead to make an antenna for picking up interferences from other devices/boards.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Rahmany ...
For example, here are simulations that "explain" somewhat the behavior of the scope probes, and the "problem" of "long" ground clip (L1 10nH (/cm?) -> 160 nH).

Transient Analysis

[image]

AC Analysis

[image]